# Fit circle patch overflowing outside view in Matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib

```
import matplotlib
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.patches import Circle
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
matplotlib.rcParams["figure.figsize"]=(6.4, 4.8)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

circle1 = Circle((0.1, 0.1), 0.2, facecolor = "k", edgecolor = 'red', linewidth = 30)
circle2 = Circle((0.5, 0.5), 0.2, facecolor = "k")

ax.axis("equal")


ax.add_artist(circle1);
ax.add_artist(circle2);

plt.show()
```

When I run the above code, which tries to draw 2 circles, the patches overflow outside the visible area. How can I fit both circles into view ?

Comment: You can calculate the extents (because you know where the circle s are) and set them with `ax.set_xlim` and `ax.set_ylim`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, to add a patch to an axes, use `ax.add_patch()`.
Then to make sure the axes is scaled according to its content, use `ax.autoscale()`

```
ax.add_artist(circle1)
ax.add_artist(circle2)
ax.autoscale()
```

[image]